# how to use user defined library the same way we use pre-defined libraries

Tags: c++, c

i mean while using user defined libraries in c we write:

```
#include "libname.h"
```

but for predefined libraries we use angular brackets instead of quotes.

```
#include <libname.h>
```

I want to include my library in predefined libraries and want use them in the same way we use predefined libraries.

Comment: can u plz elaborate more what exactly u want to do

Comment: Just remove `.h` from your header file name. I'm not sure why you'd want to do that though

Answer (score 0):

Every compiler supports a way for *including additional directories*. And any file contained in these directories will be able to be included with its name enclosed by angular brackets.

For example  [gcc](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-i.html) provides `-I` option:

```
gcc -ImyPath myfile.c ...
```

If `myHeader.h` is contained in `myPath` directory, `myfile.c` can include it in this way

```
#include <myHeader.h>
```

Check the guide of your compiler to discover how this is achieved by it. If you are using a graphical IDE you will find for sure this capability in your project option (check *compiler options*).